# get the list of partition keys in a dynamodb with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Actually, I'm using `scan` and take the partition key in every item but that's really not efficient, my dynamodb is too big and it takes too much time.

Is there a way to `query` only the partition key so we have an optimized unexpensive way to get all the partition key of a dynamoDB with boto3 in python ?

My precise goal is to get informations from the 50 latest element of my dynamoDB.
My dynamoDB has a lot of informations in the column `form_data` so first, I want to get the ID of 50 latest `creation_file_date` in an inexpensive call so after that I can make optimized call on every element.

[image: dynamoDB example]

Comment: No there is not. You have to design a solution in the database for this access pattern. If you give us more information about the entities that you want to retrieve we can help you with the design.

Comment: @desoss I precised my personal problematic to give more context.
But I think the first problematic is really general.

Answer (score 2):

### Scan

As you mentioned the only way to get a list of keys is via `Scan`. To reduce your latency you can use [`ParallelScan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan) however its still quite inefficient for your use case.

### Global Secondary Index

My recommendation would be to use a GSI to provide you the ability of 50 latest elements. In my example, I assume your peak write throughput will never exceed 1000 WCU, if it does, you will need to write shard your index attribute.

Create an index with a static value as partition key and `creation_file_date` as sort key.

#### Base Table

| creation_file_date | clients | data | gsi_pk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CR 19/01/2023 18:00 |  |  | 1 |
| CR 19/01/2023 19:00 |  |  | 1 |
| CR 19/01/2023 20:00 |  |  | 1 |
| CR 18/01/2023 21:00 |  |  | 1 |

#### Global Secondary Index

| gsi_pk | creation_file_date | clients | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CR 18/01/2023 21:00 |  |  |
| 1 | CR 19/01/2023 18:00 |  |  |
| 1 | CR 19/01/2023 19:00 |  |  |
| 1 | CR 19/01/2023 20:00 |  |  |

#### Get Last 50 Elements by `creation_file_date`

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name test1 \
--index-name test-index \
--key-condition-expression "gsi_pk = :id" \
--expression-attribute-values  '{":id":{"N":"1"}' \
--scan-index-forward false \
--limit 50 \
--return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Query and Scan will read a maximum of 1MB of data from your table or secondary indexes.

Comment: This is why pagination was created. The query is efficient and will only read 50 items. There is no solution which is more efficient.

Comment: I agree, the solution is good. Nevertheless, the question clearly states, "My dynamo DB has a lot of information in the column form_data".  So he has to be sure the items don't weigh more than 20KB on average. Otherwise, he has to reduce the page size.

Comment: What is wrong with paginating? Sure, there is a 1MB limit per page, but you can always retrieve more pages seamlessly. There is no alternate solution which is more efficient.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. Your answer is perfect. I  was just trying to warn @Utopion about the 1MB limitation.

Comment: Agreed, it's a valid point for all of multi-item reads from DynamoDB.